# create hyperlinks from data in database using php

Tags: php, mysql, database, hyperlink

I am new to both mysql and php and i need help
I am trying to display data from the databse and then display them in a php form. The data displayed should be in hyperlinks so that when the user clicks on it, it brings them to another page with more details. I have already managed to display the data from the database, how do i go about making the data as hyperlinks and connecting them to the next page?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysql_resource) )
{
$link = $row['link'] //do whatever your calculation to create links.
  $e =<<<A_TAG
<a href="{$link}" >A Link</a>
A_TAG;
  echo $e;
  echo "<br />";
}
```

Comment: And after the post? And the whatever calculation?
Tough question eh? :D

Comment: I am new at stackoverflow, So I don't downvote for less informative questions if they can be answered .But in this try I get myself downvoted.

Comment: I didn't downvote and will even vote you up. This question is evasive, he didn't try himself, don't bother on these...

Comment: will be more selective :)